# Function to apply to a linearly increasing positive real number to reach an arbitrary limit

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I've got a friend who is making a browser game and he's trying to figure out how to make a function that acts like a logarithm in that it returns higher values quickly but eventually mellows out and reaches a limit.

For example, say someone invests "points" into a characters speed. This person should get less and less speed boost for every point they put in. 1 point gives maybe .10 back as a direct modifier on speed things (this character would now be 10 percent faster than other characters with no points).  2 points might give back .19 total(.1 + .09), 3 would be .26 total(.1 + .09 + .07), etc (only an example, not the expected results).

Is there a way someone can help us understand a good way to come about this so that we can play with the numbers a bit and tweak bonuses for balance?

I have a feeling someone will have to help me with tags and whether this is the right place to ask this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention log but I think a reflected and shifted exp function might work better for what you describe. For example

$$f(x)=1-e^{-x}$$

[image: reflected and shifted exp function]

More generally you may vary this idea introducing and adjusting some parameters, say $a,b,c$ and consider the function

$$f(x)=a-b e^{-c x}$$

Comment: Whenever I see something like this that I know I knew at one point I wonder about all the other things that I have forgotten over the years :/ Thank you very much for this answer!

Answer (score -1):

A logarithmic function will do. In fact, any increasing, concave-down function will do. That is, the function must have a positive but decreasing derivative. See [Diminishing Returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminishing_returns).

I'm not here to give you an exact function. You'll have to tweak it yourself to get the numbers right. However if you start with $f(x) = \ln(x)$ and provide necessary transformations (translations, dilations, etc.) then you should be able to tweak it as necessary.

Go to [Desmos.com](http://desmos.com/calculator), type in
$$ y= a \ln (bx - h) + k $$
and add sliders for $a$, $b$, $h$, and $k$. Play around with them and see what happens.

---

I might add that if you're looking for a *linear* decrease in returns, your function must be *quadratic*. For example, if your returns are
$$ 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, \dots $$
then this means your function's derivative is decreasing at a constant rate (it is linear) so your original function must be of the form
$$ y = ax^2 + bx + c $$
where $a < 0$.

Comment: Whoa, thank you for the link to Desmos.com, that is super cool.  I am using it to play with your function and Mirko's function at the moment.